# GPU Programming (non-CUDA) and Object Oriented design

Tags: gpu, opencl

Working on an Object-Oriented C++ library and I want to take advantage of my Intel Graphics GPU. I tried to learn some OpenCL only to find out it doesn't support C++ O.O programming style and classes. Any suggestions of libraries or frameworks that could make it easier to tap into the GPU would be really helpful.

Many thanks,
Amine

Comment: Which kind of operations do you want to accelerate? Image Processing, Neural Networks, Data Structures?

Comment: @Sebastian so far only data structures in C++, such as the ones in the STL.

Comment: Then probably you should look into libraries like Thrust: https://thrust.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (and [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)) are specialized programming languages, because GPGPUs are very specialized heterogeneous computing devices.

You might perhaps be interested in semi-automatic translation of some subset of C code (or Fortran) to these, but there is [*No Silver Bullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet). Either use a library (e.g. [TensorFlow](https://tensorflow.org/)) ported to GPGPUs or accept the idea of difficult development efforts specific to your GPGPU hardware.

Look into [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC), [TransPyle](https://github.com/mbdevpl/transpyle), [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), [VEXCL](https://vexcl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), etc.

Read also [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/151478489.pdf) about SYCL.

Comment: Thanks! I took upon the task of figuring out OpenCL fundamentals, which is cross-platform and should help understanding how GPU memory and computation works in a bit of detail.